# Text color not affected by transition?

Tags: html, css

I have text which is meant to fade from blue to yellow in 1 second. For some reason, even though the background color fades in the time set, the actual text of the hyperlink just changes to yellow instantly as if no transition is cast upon it. Here's the relevant code:

```
<div id="container" class="text">
<a id="hypertext" href="Mental Enhancement.html" style="font-family:arial;font-size:120%;
text-decoration:none;">Text here to change color</a>
</div>

#hypertext {
padding:5px;
border-radius:10px;
-webkit-transition:color 1s;
-o-transition:color 1s;
-moz-transition:color 1s;
-ms-transition:color 1s;
transition:color 1s;
-webkit-transition:background-color 1s;
-o-transition:background-color 1s;
-moz-transition:background-color 1s;
-ms-transition:background-color 1s;
transition:background-color 1s;
}


#hypertext:hover {
background-color:red;
color:yellow;
}


#container {
position:relative;
}


a:link, a:visited, a:active {
color:black;
}


.text {
left:200px;
bottom:35px;
width:243px;
}
```

Anyone know why this text just instantly jumps color with no 'fade' transition? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have written the `transition` property 2 times, the 2:nd `transition` overwrites the first, so do like this:

`transition: color 1s, background-color 1s;`

```css
#hypertext {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: color 1s, background-color 1s;
  -o-transition: color 1s, background-color 1s;
  -moz-transition: color 1s, background-color 1s;
  -ms-transition: color 1s, background-color 1s;
  transition: color 1s, background-color 1s;  
}
#hypertext:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: yellow;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
}
a:link,
a:visited,
a:active {
  color: black;
}
.text {
  left: 200px;
  /*bottom: 35px;*/
  width: 243px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="text">
  <a id="hypertext" href="Mental Enhancement.html" style="font-family:arial;font-size:120%;
text-decoration:none;">Text here to change color</a>
</div>
```